# Bootstrap: How to have two dropdown items in the same row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a login form in a **Bootstrap's navbar dropdown** and I want the lowest item to be **two items, in the same row split in half(login/register)** But I can't get it done

[here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iANa.png) what it looks like

the dropdown section:

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Login
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark dropdown-menu-end bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form method="POST" , enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <li><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"
                        class="form-control bg-dark border-0 text-light"></li>
                <li><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                        class="form-control bg-dark border-0 text-light"></li>
                <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider border-top border-secondary">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="dropdown-item btn btn-dark border-0 d-inline-block">Login</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="dropdown-item btn btn-dark border-0 d-inline-block">Register</a>
                </li>
            </form>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style="display: inline-block;" to your link

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Login
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark dropdown-menu-end bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form method="POST" , enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <li><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"
                        class="form-control bg-dark border-0 text-light"></li>
                <li><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                        class="form-control bg-dark border-0 text-light"></li>
                <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider border-top border-secondary">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="dropdown-item btn btn-dark border-0 d-inline-block">Login</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" style="display: inline-block;" class="dropdown-item btn btn-dark border-0 d-inline-block">Register</a>
                </li>
            </form>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the `d-inline-block` does the same but it doesnt work

Comment: This mean there is style override this style can you show me full html to check overide stylesheet